# SSMS 18.8 crashes when re-docking tabs

Tags: sql-server, ssms, ssms-18

When I un-dock a tab in SQL Server Management Studio and later attempt to re-dock it, SSMS crashes. This happens every time, and I can reproduce the problem at will. All I have to do is un-dock a tab (let's say, in order to view two SQL queries in different tabs side-by-side) and then attempt to re-dock it, and SSMS will crash. Looking at the Event Viewer, I find two successive error messages each time the crash happens, the first with its Source set to ".NET Runtime" and the second with its source set to "Application Error" in the Event Viewer:

Message #1:

> Application: Ssms.exe Framework Version: v4.0.30319 Description: The
> process was terminated due to an unhandled exception. Exception Info:
> System.NullReferenceException at
> System.Windows.Interop.HwndMouseInputProvider.HasCustomChrome(System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource,
> RECT ByRef) at
> System.Windows.Interop.HwndMouseInputProvider.GetEffectiveClientRect(IntPtr)
> at
> System.Windows.Interop.HwndMouseInputProvider.PossiblyDeactivate(IntPtr,
> Boolean) at System.Windows.Interop.HwndMouseInputProvider.Dispose() at
> System.Windows.Interop.HwndMouseInputProvider.FilterMessage(IntPtr,
> MS.Internal.Interop.WindowMessage, IntPtr, IntPtr, Boolean ByRef) at
> System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.InputFilterMessage(IntPtr, Int32,
> IntPtr, IntPtr, Boolean ByRef) at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr,
> Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr, Boolean ByRef) at
> MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(System.Object) at
> System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate,
> System.Object, Int32) at
> System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(System.Object,
> System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32, System.Delegate) at
> System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority,
> System.TimeSpan, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32) at
> MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr)

Message #2:

> Faulting application name: Ssms.exe, version: 2019.150.18369.0, time
> stamp: 0x5fd317a3 Faulting module name: PresentationCore.ni.dll,
> version: 4.8.4320.0, time stamp: 0x5fc81198 Exception code: 0xc0000005
> Fault offset: 0x0076c044 Faulting process id: 0x166c Faulting
> application start time: 0x01d6fc1a384c50f7 Faulting application path:
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio
> 18\Common7\IDE\Ssms.exe Faulting module path:
> C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\PresentationCore\627e2c47709994c2c1f8fd2e1228d567\PresentationCore.ni.dll
> Report Id: 1b2fa46b-b60c-4517-bd91-1d4de7324b26 Faulting package full
> name: Faulting package-relative application ID:

Has anyone else experienced this issue and found a fix or a workaround for it?

Comment: Feedback and bug reports for SQL Server and SSMS belong here: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server  Also this doesn't repro for me on 18.7.1

Answer (score 14):

The "fix" turned out to be this:

First, close all SSMS windows.
Next, find your SSMS executable file. Mine was in this location:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 18\Common7\IDE

(If you can't find it, try right-clicking on the shortcut you use to open SSMS and going to Properties --> Open File Location)

Once you have found this file, you will also find a file called **Ssms.exe.config** in the same folder - open Notepad in Administrator Mode and edit this **Ssms.exe.config** file.

In the **Ssms.exe.config** file, find an XML tag called **`<AppContextSwitchOverrides>`**, and APPEND (not replace) the following exactly:

```
;Switch.System.Windows.Interop.MouseInput.OptOutOfMoveToChromedWindowFix=true; Switch.System.Windows.Interop.MouseInput.DoNotOptOutOfMoveToChromedWindowFix=true
```

Then, save the file with the change you just made.

After making this change, SSMS should no longer crash or hang when you manually re-dock windows into the tab bar.

Comment: This seems to help in some cases (dragging tab order, but not undock/redocking).  SSMS still crashes when I undock (pop out) a tab by dragging it and try to redock it before/after another tab.

Comment: Worked for me for docking/undocking, thanks.

Comment: Confirm that this worked for me as well, for both dragging and docking. SSMS 18, Windows 10, latest updates as of May 2021.

Answer (score 2):

Try add this line to the `<runtime>`-section in the *****.exe.config-File which do you start.

```
<AppContextSwitchOverrides value="Switch.System.Windows.Interop.MouseInput.OptOutOfMoveToChromedWindowFix=true; Switch.System.Windows.Interop.MouseInput.DoNotOptOutOfMoveToChromedWindowFix=true" />
```

I had the same problem with Visual Studio and it helps:
[Visual Studio 2015 Isolated Shell application crashing when docking Tool window after update to MS KB4601050](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66178138/visual-studio-2015-isolated-shell-application-crashing-when-docking-tool-window/66248174#66248174)

Here is is the Microsoft-Statement: https://support.microsoft.com/de-de/topic/kumulatives-update-vom-9-februar-2021-f%C3%BCr-net-framework-3-5-und-4-8-f%C3%BCr-windows-10-version-1809-und-windows-server-version-2019-kb4601055-38aea913-ccd7-bc76-db60-9521318f97cb

Comment: Adding this line worked to fix the issue in 17.9.1 for me.

Answer (score 0):

For me uninstaling KB4601050 win10 update solved problem.

Comment: I have this update installed and still experiencing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround you can use *ALT + Minus Sign (-)* shortcut and create either a new horizontal (dock to the bottom) or vertical tab group (dock to the right).

You can do the same by right clicking the query tab.

Answer (score 0):

This was fixed in SSMS 18.9, released on April 15, 2021. Fiddling with the config file is no longer required.

> General SSMS  Fixed a crash (in the Visual Studio Shell) that was causing SSMS to crash when re-docking tabs. See [SQL Server user feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/42651556-ssms-18-8-crashes-when-re-docking-tabs)

[Release Notes for 18.9](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/release-notes-ssms?view=sql-server-ver15#189)