# Microsoft SSMS crash when moving or re-redocking tabs

Tags: sql-server, ssms

Just a few days ago SSMS starts to crash when I move or re-dock tabs. If I move a tab with right click to move them to a new vertical tab group it crash. When I right click on a tab I crash.

The very strange thing is that I have several VM running on a Mac host on Parallels.

I have read [SSMS 18.8 crashes when re-docking tabs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66103557/ssms-18-8-crashes-when-re-docking-tabs) but the solution do not work and I have upgraded to 18.9.1 and it is still there. The problem seems to have something to do with latest Microsofts Updates since it appears on all my three WM more or less simultaneously. It also crash if I try to use a older SSMS 17.

I also installed a brand new VM to test this and I also crash there.

Answer (score 0):

Could be an issue with SQL Prompt - after installing latest update 10.6.15 right-clicking a tab no longer crashes SSMS 18.9.1

Comment: Thanks, installing latest version of SQL Prompt that in my case is 10.6.14.20978 solved the problem and explains why all versions of SSMS crashed. Not very nice of RedGate to introduce that bug....:-)